# { error = "invalid_request"; "error_description" = "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"; } In swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
I am trying with this but every time I will get 

{     error = "invalid_request";     "error_description" = "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"; }

Request String: 

let headers    = [ "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

let urlString = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?"

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["grant_type":"authorization_code","code":"4/FAOYR1mQo1lN1Gdg9jDnigwZ8RP76NUrqPbYZlMCSP28","client_id":"387376833747-12pbtud9tepr4di0insdhc0d4qpf5e9m.apps.googleusercontent.com","client_secret":"xOacVhLavM9fH8SpOK4I2dRJ","redirect_uri":"https://stackoverflow.com"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                print(response.result)
        }
```

Also try with passing request parameter like this but still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send appended parameter with url while post request. 
Pass parameter as below this

```
  let headers    = [ "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","grant_type" : "authorization_code"" ]

        let urlString = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?"
            Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["code":"4/FAOYR1mQo1lN1Gdg9jDnigwZ8RP76NUrqPbYZlMCSP28","client_id":"apps.googleusercontent.com","client_secret":"","redirect_uri":"https://stackoverflow.com"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                    print(response.result)
            }
```

Comment: you need to pass as i described.

Comment: I have done same as you described but I have to pass authorization_code value other wise it give me error unresolved identifier authorization_code.

Comment: is it string value?

Comment: i though it is dynamic value so i have passed string variable there now i changed with string value .check my update answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147816/discussion-between-ios-developer-and-kkrocks).

Answer (score -1):

These error invalid_request occurs only below cases so please check with your server side what is missing or invalid.

> The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported
>   or invalid parameter value, repeats a parameter,includes multiple
>   credentials, utilizes more than one mechanism for authenticating the
>   client, or is otherwise malformed.

Comment: all needed parameter I have placed , also I have tried so many times same thing but still can't get proper result , can you please help me to solve it because of this I have to do other thing.

Comment: @IOSdeveloper can't say exactly are you working in server side code?

Comment: Yes I have implemented Server side in google playground.